# Magnetic field lines of a toroid magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

I am not sure what are the magnetic field lines of a torroid magnet like this one:

[image]

In particular, at the center of the magnet, is the field null or is it maximal?

Comment: Do you know the intended USE of this magnet? That might tell us how it is magnetised.

Comment: According to the pictures by the same seller, I am pretty sure that one face is the north pole, and the other face it the south pole.

Comment: So this could be a very large loudspeaker magnet (needing the appropriate pole-pieces to be fitted). Inside the magnet the field lines will run from South face to North face. Outside they will loop back to the South face. Some will loop round the outside of the outer periphery, some will loop through the hole in the middle. It might help to imagine the magnet as a collection of parallel bar magnets.

Comment: thx. Is the magnetic field at the center of the magnet null?

Comment: What do you mean by the centre of the magnet? Do you mean inside the magnet itself, or along the (common) geometrical axis of the inner and outer cylinders bounding the magnet itself?

Comment: Along the (common) geoemterical axis of the inner and outer cylinders.

Comment: No, it won't be null here, but point along the axis from North Pole to South Pole. See previous comment.